# Copy to Clipboard without space or break lines

Tags: javascript, html, input, clipboard, clipboard.js

I am trying to develop a "copy" button to copy numbers from a multi input form to the clipboard. I installed Clipboard.js and, point the id to the `<form>` element so, everything works fine except that the numbers of each input are copied with a break line between them. Is there any way to remove any space or break line in between?

Should I add `.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "")` somewhere?

```js
new ClipboardJS('.btn_copy', {
});
```

```css
.btn_copy {
  background: rgba(50, 50, 90, 1);
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  color: #e1e1e1;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_copy:hover {
  background: rgba(50, 50, 90, 0.9);
}

.circle input {
  border-radius: 999px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/clipboard.js/2.0.11/clipboard.js"></script>

<form id="tkt_1">
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="number" placeholder="00" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="number" placeholder="00" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="number" placeholder="00" />
  </div>
</form>

<div class="btn_copy" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-target="#tkt_1">Copy</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a special library to put things into the clipboard.  Just use `navigator.clipboard.writeText()`

Here's your same code but without needing clipboard.js or even jQuery.

```js
//Select all of the `.btn_copy` elements - this returns a NodeList
const copyButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn_copy');

//Convert the NodeList of button elements into an array of button elements
Array.from(copyButtons)
  //Now loop through each button element
  .forEach((thisButton) => {
  
    //Inside of this loop we attatch a click event listener to each button
    thisButton.addEventListener('click', (clickEvent) => {
      //When the button in clicked...
      
      //We get the value of the `data-clipboard-target` attribute on the button that was clicked
      //This is just a string with a CSS selector in it
      const clipboardTarget = thisButton.getAttribute('data-clipboard-target');

      //Now we use the CSS selector that we found to select the elements we want
      //Again this will return a NodeList
      const inputElements = document.querySelectorAll(clipboardTarget)
      
      //Convert the NodeList into an Array of elements
      const combined = Array.from(inputElements)
        //Convert this array of elements into an array of the values on each input element
        .map((element) => {
          //Basically this it a loop that returns the `value` property on each element as a string
          //This will be an array of strings
          //FTI: If you want to manipulate the value (like prefixing numbers with a 0) - you do that here
          return element.value;
        })
        //Convert this array of strings into a single string by joining all the parts together
        //The string passed in below will be inserted between each array item as they ar joined together
        //This can be any string
        .join('');
      
      //Now we have a final string assembled
      //Put that string into the clipboard!
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(combined);
    });
  });
```

```css
.btn_copy {
  background: rgba(50, 50, 90, 1);
  min-height: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 15px 50px;
  color: #e1e1e1;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn_copy:hover {
  background: rgba(50, 50, 90, 0.9);
}

.circle input {
  border-radius: 999px;
  float: left;
  max-width: 100px;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 100px;
}

.clear{clear: both;}
```

```html
<div>
<form id="tkt_1">
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="number" value="00" min="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="number" value="00" min="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="number" value="00" min="0" />
  </div>
</form>

<div class="btn_copy" data-clipboard-target="#tkt_1 .circle input">Copy</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<hr>

<form id="tkt_2">
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="number" value="00" min="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="number" value="00" min="0" />
  </div>
  <div class="circle">
    <input type="number" value="00" min="0" />
  </div>
</form>

<div class="btn_copy" data-clipboard-target="#tkt_2 .circle input">Copy</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris Barr for your answer! You are right, this is a faster way which avoid to load another library and it would be great. I tried to copy the numbers from the snippet you did but it seems not working. Is there something wrong?

Comment: It works for me in Chrome and Firefox.  Did you change the inputs to contain numbers?  The `placeholder="00"` isn't a value of `00` so that won't be copied if nothing is in there.  That could of course be changed in the code though, or maybe it would be better to just pre-fill `00` as the starting values.  I've updated my answer to reflect this now.

Comment: You're right, I set it up on my project and it works fine. Each input is limited to 2 numbers and this is just the '<form id="tkt_1"> '. Other forms with other inputs will follow such as '<form id="tkt_2">','<form id="tkt_3">' etc. Each form has its own copy button and the script should copy only the form related to each copy button. Clipboard.js makes it all work via id="tkt_1" called by the 'data-clipboard-target="#tkt_1"' of each button. Your snippet works fine, but it copies all inputs from all modules together. Is there a way to make each copy button work individually on the related form?

Comment: Yes for sure.  I've updated my answer again to show this with 2 forms and now It will use the `data-clipboard-target` to find all of the `.circle input` elements inside of the target.

Comment: You made magic! This was exactly what I had been struggling to achieve for days.
It's not really important but I would like to get rid of the ":" between each number, should I edit '.join(':')' to '.join('')' ?

Comment: Yes exactly.  That's an array of strings, and `.join('')` will smush all the array parts together with whatever string you put in there.  An empty string is perfect if you want all the numbers to be put together as one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254715/discussion-between-freddan-and-chris-barr).

Comment: This is really great! Thanks a lot Chris. I would like to ask you one last thing to keep learning: I noticed that in your snippet you didn't point the btn_copy to the <form id="tkt_1"> but the 'const target' points to '.circle input'. How is it possible that by clicking on the first copy button it does not also copy to the clipboard the inputs of the forms below which have the same classes?

Comment: Sure!  It's harder to explain in the comments here, so I just added a bunch of code comments to my answer.  See that again. I also made some very minor changes, but I think it's all explained.  The quick version though is that the `const target` was building a string that combined what was in the `data-clipboard-target` attribute with the `.circle input` string to make a complete CSS selector.  I've changed it now so that full selector is in the attribute, which is simpler and easier to understand

Comment: You are a Master! Thanks to your explanation everything is very clear and I learned a lot. I'm still analyzing the various steps described which help me to understand the code structure and to use the same on the next codes I will develop

Answer (score 0):

To remove any space or line break from a string you can use the `replace` method with `'\n'` for the line break and `' '` for the space.

```js
const formatedText = str.replace('\n', '').replace(' ', '')
copy(formatedText)
```

Keep in mind that the statement `copy(formatedText)` is just symbolic. Use anything you want or need to copy the value to the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks @Vinicius Bazanella for your answer, I think this is what I was looking for. How can I integrate it with the library Clipboard.js? Should I declare it before initializing clipboard.js, so that the text to be copied is already "prepared" without breaks or spaces?